# Python discord bot deletes every message except specific ones

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

it's my first time coding something and making a discord bot. But I've been trying to figure it out what is wrong with this code for a long time. I want one channel to only able to type specific words and delete everything else, but in this code no matter what i do it deletes everything, cheers

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
intents = discord.Intents(message_content=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('BOTCADO ONLINE')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if (message.channel.id == 'id'):
    
    if (message.content != "cado"):
      await message.delete()


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

i tried basically everything

Comment: Your intents are wrong. You pass the Client `default` intents & then have an unused variable that has `message_content`. You should pass intents with `message_content` enabled into the Client's init instead.

Comment: I'm sorry how i'm going to do that, which lines i should change

Comment: I'm not gonna tell you exactly which lines and words to change, it's not that hard. Take a look at the examples in the docs and see how those work

Comment: thank you for real, but i did the one in the answers and have to put "from discord.ext import commands" it start working, But now i'm trying to figure how would i make multiple "cado"'s are able to stay in the chat, and also with the capital words as well, i tried to make a list and add all combinations in that list then checked if messafe.content != that list it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get it to work I changed:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
intents = discord.Intents(message_content=True)
```

to:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)
```

I would only use the intents you need to use however. I only put all for testing proposes.

Also in this line of code, `if (message.channel.id == 'id'):`, message.channel.id is being set equal to a string. Message ID's are integers. You have to remove that conditional / replace it. You could set the message ID that corresponds with the channel you want to delete messages in by declaring the id as a variable first at the top of your code. `id = < THE CHANNEL ID >`

Comment: it worked after i did "from discord.ext import commands" this, thank you